# Text in two.js wont show up

Tags: javascript, text, two.js

I have a program that shows an expanding circle. At the end, i want it to display a randomly generated item from the array called list.

[The Code](https://codepen.io/Fried_Squid/project/editor/ZBKGBp/%22Here%20is%20the%20codepen%22)

Here is the code in particular

```
var list = ["list","of","names"];
var person = ("")
person = list[Rnd(0,2)]; 
var text1 = new Two.Text(person ,250,250, 'normal');
```

and

```
text1.value = person;
text1.fill = '#FFFFFF';
text1.stroke ='#FFFFFF';
text1.visible = true;
```

EDIT:

i specifically want to use twos text not HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the effect by using the circle's radius as a condition to add the text. I made the circle's radius 100 to start.

```
var circle = two.makeCircle(two.width / 2, two.height / 2, 100);
circle.fill = "orange";
var list = ["list","of","names"];
var person = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
var text1 = new Two.Text(person, two.width / 2, two.height / 2, 'normal');
text1.fill = '#FFFFFF';
text1.stroke ='#FFFFFF';
```

The bind loop plays the circle animation. Once the circle expands to a radius of 200, it stops the animation, and adds the text1 to the two canvas.

```
two.bind('update', function() {
  if (circle.radius > 200) {
    two.pause();
    two.add(text1);
  }
  circle.radius++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the circle reaches a certain width.

generate a random number according to your array size then set the value of your element using `getElementById` with your `list[i]` ( i = your random number ).

Answer (score -1):

Do this for all the text:

```
two.scene.add(text);
```